# https urls in coherence emails when phoenix is behind a proxy

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have my phoenix app set up behind nginx. Nginx is serving https traffic.

I want emails from coherence to contain https urls like `https://my_domain.com/...`, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Here is my app's config:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 8080],
  url: [host: "my_domain.com", port: 443],
  # ...
```

With this config, urls in emails are like this: `my_domain.com:443/some_path`. And when I remove `port: 443`, they became `my_domain.com:8080/some_path`. And adding `force_ssl: [hsts: true]` doesn't help too.

Of cource I could set `url: [host: "my_domain.com", port: 80]` and set nginx to redirect all http requests to port 443, but it seems wrong to me. I could edit email templates to force https urls, but this also seems wrong.

Or maybe using a proxy in front of an erlang app is not an erlang way and I just didn't get it yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set `scheme` to `"https"`. This should work:

```
config :my_app, MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 8080],
  url: [host: "my_domain.com", port: 443, scheme: "https"],
  # ...
```

Comment: No, this didn't work for me. I've tried `[host: "my_domain.com", scheme: "https"]` and `[host: "my_domain.com", port: 443, scheme: "https"]` but in both cases got: `** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in URI.default_port/1` `(elixir) lib/uri.ex:44: URI.default_port(:https)`

Comment: Are you sure that error is from `scheme: "https"` not `scheme: :https`? `"https"` works for me.

Comment: Yeah, this is my mistake: I wrote :https. `[host: "my_domain.com", port: 443, scheme: "https"]` works great, thank you. Please confirm adding port: 443 to your answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Vizvamitra it should work without `port` like I said in the answer. Can you try that out?

Comment: @Vizvamitra you're right. Just accepted your edit and removed one sentence I wrote since it was wrong.